# Why SQL primary key index begin at 1 and not at 0?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

was wondering, why does the SQL primary key index begin at 1, and why not at 0 ? Is there a reason ?

I don't know if this is the good place to ask a question like this, but found no answer on the web.

Comment: Because why not? Also: probably because 0 can be 'confused' with `null` in some languages (looking at you, PHP) and could cause all kinds of trouble.

Comment: Primary key indices don't start at any value, because (in theory) any column can be made a primary key.  I presume you are referring to the auto increment sequence.  Assuming it does start at 1 by default, why does that bother you?

Comment: Is this giving you a problem, or are you just curious?

Comment: Most of the time the column is a signed integer. Why not start from `-2,147,483,648`? Mostly because it's a faff, there's no need, starting from 1 gives maximum compatibility with other data types and conventions.

Comment: @ADyson I am just curious about this, no problem with this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Counting in SQL generally starts as "1".  For instance, the substring operations count characters in a string from 1 (and not 0).  `row_number()` enumerates rows in a group, starting from 1 (and not 0).

The reason for this is simple.  Humans start counting at 1 -- just ask many four-year olds.  We don't start counting at zero until we learn programming.  As a species, we counted from "1" for many millennia before adding zero to the pantheon of numbers.

Counting from 1 is much more intuitive when you are counting rows from tables:  "1" for the first row requires little explanation, in particular for people who are not programmers.  "0" for the first row requires explanation.

It is easy to forget, but SQL was devised for non-programmers.  Much of the verbosity is because it was intended for business users.

Answer (score 2):

use this   `SET [GLOBAL|SESSION] sql_mode='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'`
then it will start from 0

[mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html)

Comment: This is specifically for MySQL (which, granted, this question is tagged with) but AFAIK _all_ RDBMS'es start at 1, not just MySQL.

Comment: also the question was _why_, not _how_

Answer (score 2):

The sql standard  4.15.11 Identity columns -
https://www.sis.se/api/document/preview/916885/ says 'an identity column has a start value an end value an increment and a cycle option' it doesn't say that it should start at any specific number but since it's purpose is the provision of a unique row number (if set as primary key) then a negative start value would be meaningless. MYSQL will allow you to set the start value to 0 if you wish but I don't see the point. In my view allowing array subscripts to start from 0 in other languages was always daft and mysql having a limit offset clause which starts at 0 is an annoying inconsistency.